# python3.8 import manager cant find lzma std lib

Tags: python, import, lzma, centos8

I have installed python3.8 from redhat repo

> dnf install python38

on clean CentOS 8. When I run my app.py script the following appears.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    import instaloader
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instaloader/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .instaloader import Instaloader
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 3, in <module>
    import lzma
  File "/opt/python38/lib/python3.8/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

Note that I have everything tested and working on other fedora 31 system and seems that all the required rpm package are installed in favour lzma to be functioning as I need for.

Comment: Have you tried importing `_lzma` yourself?

Comment: I have tried with the same result.

Comment: Have you tried the same code with python 3.7 or any other versions?

Comment: Yes, and it works with python3.6 which is built-in.